# Need help understanding why $f(k+1) \leq \int_k^{k+1} f(x) \, dx \leq f(k)$ in the following context:

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to know why the inequality (6.26 in the below pasted solution) $f(k+1) \leq \int_k^{k+1} f(x) \, dx \leq f(k)$ is true. It feels true intuitively since $f$ is a mono decreasing function and the segment length is $1$, but I can't figure out analytically how to show it is true.

The original question is:
[image: Baby Rudin ex 6.8]

And its solution is:

[image: solution]

Comment: To be more specific, how did we go from $f(k+1) \leq f(x) \leq f(k)$ to the said inequality.

Comment: $f \leq g$ implies $\int_a^{b} f(x)d x\leq \int_a^{b} g(x)d x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(k+1)$ is a constant not a function, and $f(k+1) \leq f(x)$ meaning $f(k+1)(k+1 -k) = f(k+1) = \int_{k}^{k+1}f(k+1) \leq \int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)$. The other inequality is the same.

Comment: $f(k)$ being a constant is exactly what I overlooked. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem for integrals implies (for $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$) that $\int_a^b f(t)dt=(b-a)f(c)$ for some $c \in [a,b].$ Replace $a$ by $k$ and $b$ by $k+1$ in this and use monotonicity.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} f(n) 1_{[n,n+1)}(x)$ and note that
$\phi(x) \ge f(x) \ge \phi(x+1) \ge 0$.

$\int_1^{N+1} \phi(x) dx  = \sum_{n=1}^N f(n) \ge \int_1^{N+1} f(x) dx \ge \int_1^{N+1} \phi(x+1) dx = \int_2^{N+2} \phi(x) dx = \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} f(n)$,
that is
$\sum_{n=1}^N f(n) \ge \int_1^{N+1} f(x) dx \ge \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} f(n)$.

Note that all three quantities are non increasing functions of $N$.

If $\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$ converges then $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_1^{N+1} f(x) dx$ exists and if $\int_1^{N+1} f(x) dx$ converges then $\lim_{N \to \infty}  \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$ exists.